# List CPAN modules that have been made but not installed

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

Is there an easy/clean way to do this in Linux/ a Linux-like environment?

**Purpose**

My aim is to run CPAN with admin permissions only during the installation phase, not at the get/make/test phases.

Comment: What does "have been made" mean?

Comment: @daxim: CPAN builds modules in four stages: IIRC, these are - it GETs and unpacks tarballs from mirrors, it MAKEs them by running a configure script to create a Makefile, and then runs `make`, it TESTs by running `make test`, and then it installs by running `make install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using CPAN.pm for that, I have a somewhat unorthodox suggestion.

Make a subclass of CPAN.pm, which actually publishes the results/stages of each module it works with to a registry (via a suplied callback API to make the registry implementation flexible).

Then you need to simply check that registry.

(or you can try to put that as a patch into CPAN.pm itself)

Comment: I'm using CPAN.pm, yes. Should I gather that CPAN doesn't record any state outside the results of make, and so the answer to the exact question I asked is: Sorry, you can't do that?

Comment: +1: unorthodox suggestion: It's a nice idea.  Better than logging, for my purposes, would be to touch files as each stage is successfully completed, which might be called `cpan-did-make`, `cpan-did-test`, &c.

Answer (score 2):

The [CPAN configuration items](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN#Config_Variables) `make_install_make_command` and `mbuild_install_build_command` deal with this. Change them to enable `sudo` support.

Comment: This isn't what i was after, but it would certainly be helpful.  `o conf make_install_make_command` says it is bound to `sudo make`, but installing fails when trying to write to system bin directories, claiming `\usr\bin\make` lacks permission...

Comment: You're mistaken, this is **exactly** what you want. These configuration items were specifically added for this scenario so that people do not run the full cpan, especially the testing step, with elevated privileges. Make resides at `/usr/bin/make`, note the forward slashes. Correct your configuration and try again.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I asked for, because I had very many made, tested and uninstalled cpan modules that I was hoping that I wouldn't have to test&install again.  Writing a script based "make -n" told me what I needed - it appears CPAN doesn't keep track of the right things to help.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of documenting an approach that seems promising, but doesn't work - the shell command:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print | while read -r DIR; do pushd $DIR;  make -q; mk=$?; make -q install; inst=$?; make -q test; tst=$?; echo Directory "$DIR $mk $inst $tst"; popd; done| fgrep -ve /build
```

when executed in the cpan build dir lists the exit statuses of make -q for "", "test" and "install", which says whether that make goal needs any work to achieve.

But all have nonzero exit statuses, which means they all will do something if you execute them, even if the make has successfully been completed.  So you can't tell anything this way.